# Principal Bundle Definition Question Action restriction

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Let $G$ be a topological group and $\pi: P\rightarrow M$ a fiber bundle with fiber $G$ (working in continuous category). We say that $\pi$ is a principal G-bundle if

(1) $G$ acts freely on the right of $P$.

(2) For each $p\in M$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$  and a fiber preserving homeomorphism $\phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times G$  that is G-equivariant.

My question is,  G-equivariantness of $\phi$ implicitly assumes that the action $G$ on $P$ restricts to an action $G$ on $\pi^{-1}(U)$. I was wondering if that is indeed always the case, or should there be a third alternative condition stating that to be the case?

Comment: You forgot to assume that $\pi\circ g=\pi$ for every $g\in G$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That's not part of the definition

Comment: Yes, it is a part of the definition: It ensures that $G$ does act on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ by the restriction of the action on $P$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah I see. The book i'm looking at did not have that assumption included as part of the definition. But now I see. Thanks!